# FormatException was Unhandled while converting string to Int32

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, formatexception

So I wrote [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361670/how-to-select-a-tabitem-based-off-of-its-header) yesterday. I am still using the solution under **UPDATE**, but for some reason I am now receiving a `FormatException was Unhandled` error. Under the error, the compiler window says that the `Input string was not in a correct format`. Why would this be happening?

When I was looking into the error I thought that maybe I'd have better luck using `Int32.TryParse`, like in [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx). But it was pretty much the same deal.

This is what I currently have...

```
//Initializing a parent TreeView Item
TreeViewItem parentItem = (TreeViewItem)SelectedItem.Parent;

//This is the call to getNumber that I am having trouble with.
//It is located in an if statement, but I didn't bother to write out the
//whole statement because I didn't want to add surplus code
int curNumber = getNumber(parentItem.Header.ToString());

//Gets the number contained in a Node's header
public static int getNumber(string parentNodeHeader)
{
      int curNumber = 0;
      curNumber = Convert.ToInt32(parentNodeHeader); //**FormatException!!
      return curNumber;
}
```

Note: The nodes that I click on to make this error appear do not have number values in them. However, their parents do (Which is what I don't understand because I am passing the parent's `header` to the function).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `Int32.TryParse` should not raise an exception...

```
//Gets the number contained in a Node's header
public static int getNumber(string parentNodeHeader)
{
      int curNumber;
      //if parse to Int32 fails, curNumber will still be 0
      Int32.TryParse(parentNodeHeader, out curNumber);
      return curNumber;
}
```

**EDIT** :

Seems that you should do something like that (somme null check would be better, of course)

```
//Initializing a parent TreeView Item
var parentItem = (TreeViewItem)SelectedItem.Parent;
var header = (TextBlock)parentItem.Header;
int curNumber = getNumber(header.Text);
```

Comment: Alright, that took care of the exception. But `Int32.TryParse` is failing because `curNumber` is returning 0. Is there anything I could show you that would help you to explain why?

Comment: @Ericafterdark well, you should try to debug slowly, see what's in parentItem, then in parentItem.Header...

Comment: Well my parent node's header is set to a `TextBlock`, is that a problem? Inside the `if` statement I get the correct value for `parentItem`, but then when it passes to `getNumber`, `parentNodeHeader` displays `"System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock"` as it's Value.

Comment: @Ericafterdark I edited my answer, can you test the EDIT part ?

Comment: I get an `InvalidCastException` on `var header = ...`

Comment: I ended up adding the `var header = ...` line to the `if` statement and now it is working as expected. Thanks for your help!